# Image View causing to crash

Tags: android

I just need some quick help. I am using android eclipse making a android application for college when i try to find the image view the emulator crash if i comment it out it works fine.

can someone please tell me where i am going wrong

```
package com.example.diceandmusic;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Random nextDiceFace = new Random();
    //ImageView diceFaceImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.diceFaceImage);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void rollDiceClick()
    {
        switch(nextDiceFace.nextInt(6)+1)
        {
        case 1:
            //diceFaceImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.one);
            break;

        case 2:
            //diceFaceImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.two);
            break;

        case 3:
            //diceFaceImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.three);
            break;

        case 4:
            //diceFaceImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.four);
            break;

        case 5:
            //diceFaceImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.five);
            break;

        case 6:
            //diceFaceImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.six);
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because your `diceFaceImageView`  was **null** as Activity unable to bind `ImageView` to `diceFaceImageView` from layout xml file,

Just put this line,

```
diceFaceImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.diceFaceImage);
```

after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` `in onCreate()`

Like,

```
Random nextDiceFace = new Random();
ImageView diceFaceImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        diceFaceImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.diceFaceImage);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You must first call

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Before instantiating

```
ImageView diceFaceImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.diceFaceImage);
```

The correct thing to do would be declaring the Imageview as a class variable, and instantiating it after you set the ContentView

```
Random nextDiceFace = new Random();
ImageView diceFaceImageView = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    diceFaceImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.diceFaceImage);
}
```